# SteemJS not working in Firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, blockchain

I have  a problem with connecting Steem using SteemJs https://github.com/adcpm/steem

Problem appears only on firefox browser, but Chrome Works correctly.

Our app is coded in Yii2 and JavaScript, 
which works fully in front-end

```
<script src="//cdn.steemjs.com/lib/latest/steem.min.js"></script>
<script>
          steem.broadcast.comment('5K8eZVEAMkfejyHxeQJ9R4wvrXowwz7kcxcTVwFGpeGq1x2iKRb', 
             '', 
             ‘test', 
             'sci', 
             'this-is-a-test-article-2', 
             'this is a test article2', 
             'test', 
             '', 
            function(err, result) {
                console.log(err, result);
        });
```

Problem in the following process:
When running request to blockchain , it return null in Chrome.
Null is mean ok! so everything is fine

But when running on Firefox error occures:

```
Error: 3030000 tx_missing_posting_auth: missing required posting authority
Missing Posting Authority sci

…..
 {"ops":[["comment",    {"parent_author":"","parent_permlink":"test","author":"sci","permlink":"this-is-a-test-article-2","title":"this is a test article2","body":"test","json_metadata":"\"\""}]],"sigs":    ["STM7x7kJhdKzu7gie8gPg5uUDNmLjbcXx7ek2H8UtKxH8qub3V2ut"]}
th_a  transaction.cpp:172 verify_authority
```

Sigs here - is always different,but should be same and must be equal to public key from private: GLS8MfcHZyYioPBsmoYp8AZf4mbwZdsarunFRvuWUySqb3nwPeRwb.

In chrome it is working right key.

This is browser-compatibility problem, or browser feature problem
Please help identify a problem, and possible we can patch it or overcome in another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm install adcpm/steem#dev
```

Just build it from develop branch and problem will solved. In lib folder you can find steem.min.js.

Comment: Thank you! npm install -S adcpm/steem#dev Works